# How to trigger project.xml of Maven 1.0.2 version in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting below when it triggers it in Jenkins. It is looking for `pom.xml` but `pom.xml` is not there only `project.xml` is there. Is there any plugin for that?

> ERROR: Failed to parse POMs  org.kohsuke.stapler.framework.io.IOException2: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: Couldn't find maven version information in 'D:\VWHoAS\maven-1.0.2'. Are you sure that this is a valid maven home?  at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:74)  at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:42)  at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)  at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:627)  at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)  at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)  at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)  at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)  at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381)  Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: Couldn't find maven version information in 'D:\VWHoAS\maven-1.0.2'. Are you sure that this is a valid maven home?  at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.getMavenVersion(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:198)  at hudson.maven.MavenVersionCallable.call(MavenVersionCallable.java:70)  ... 8 more

Comment: Really Maven 1.X ? I assume that will not work cause it is tooooo old...

Comment: Can you show the snippet from your jenkins job? Invoke top-level maven targets has a POM field in advanced options.. you can type in project.xml there and it will build from that.

Comment: What you should do is if you really want to use Maven 1? Use a freestyle job...otherwise it will never work...

Comment: i created a free style project and i select invoke top-level maven targets in add post build steps. then it asks for maven version , goals , pom...